# Can I get rid of JBoss default deploy directory artifacts, and how?

Tags: java, jboss

I just downloaded JBoss 4.0.4.GA and see there's a lot of JARs and WARs already located inside its default `deploy/` directory. According to [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossDeployDirectory) page, this is normal, however I'm wondering: *do I absolutely need this stuff*? What if I just want to run my app WAR and nothing else? Is it safe to get rid of these other artifacts or does JBoss need them to start properly?

If it is fine to get rid of them, then how? Just delete them, or do I need to do something from an admin app or config file, etc.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is information on tuning and trimming JBoss 3 and 4: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossASTuningSlimming

Keep what you need and take out what you don't...